# Widget to create Shortcut of Installed Apps

Tags: android, android-widget

How to create shortcut for pre-installed apps from my widget?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want some static shortcuts?  Just pre-installed apps?

This is how I created what look like shortcuts on the home screen:

```
RemoteViewsWidget views = new RemoteViewsWidget(context, R.layout.your_layout);
```

Where RemoteViewsWidget is your subclass of RemoteViews.  You'll want the context to use for actions done in the RemoteViewsWidget class.

In a method in the RemoteViewsWidget class, I set the image and text for the "shortcut":

```
setImageViewUri(imageResId, uri);
setTextViewText(textResId, displayName);
```

Where imageResId is the resource in your layout you want to be your thumnail and the uri points to the image (I used a locally saved file for the image source).  Similar for the textResId and displayName.

```
setOnClickPendingIntent(layoutViewId, PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, requestCode, intent, flags));
```

Here, layoutViewId is the parent layout that your image view and text view live in.  This layout is what triggers the intent when it is selected.  The pending intent is what is executed when the layout is selected - just fill in your context, intent of the activity you want launched and flags, if necessary.

To find what you need from the apps to launch them, you probably want to use PackageManager:

```
List<ResolveInfo> appInfos = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER), 0);
```

to get a list of the resolve info for all apps in your launcher.  You can get all you need from that list to make the intent for the setOnClickPendingIntent above.  If you only want a subset of these apps, you can apply a different or more categories, different actions, etc.  Or you can just use known packages or activities.

After you've created your remote views, you need to update the widget, either in a utility method or in your widget provider subclass:

```
views.updateWidget(); // update resources with image, text and intent as above
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).updateAppWidget(
        widgetId, views);
```